# How do I put on a widget in my own Stack Exchange profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, widgets

I saw that someone put a widget or `.gif` into their profile section on Stack Overflow.

How can I put on a widget in my own profile?

---

[UPDATE]:

e.g.

- This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3423768/ravexina) added a flair widget of Stack Exchange on his profile.
- This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) added a [nerdy score](https://www.nerdtests.com/ft_nq.php) widget of Stack Exchange on his profile.
- This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng) added the donate widget.

Comment: I think it helps if you share a link to said user profile. As far as I'm aware you can only embed an image but you can do some trickery with that if the image is hosted on a server you control.

Comment: @rene Ok, I will update my question.

Comment: Okay, I found the answer that demonstrates how you can have some interaction [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258866/158100) but be warned that the server-side bits are now gone and replaced with a NSFW site so don't click anything there (I already did that for you) but you get some idea what coulld be possible.

Comment: Regarding donate widget: it's an ordinary image with ordinary link. No real widget i.e. no script or anything. (All the logic is made on paypal.com side when processing the link)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After login go to :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair
```

Simply copy and paste the provided HTML snippet wherever you want to show off your Stack Overflow flair. You can find various option (color / combine various SO account ...) to display your flair.

Your link to edit profile:

[image: Edit your profile to add flair]

**Update because request in comment:**

After complete nerd test its give you html like below:

```
<a href="http://www.nerdtests.com/ft_nq.php">
<img src="https://www.nerdtests.com/images/ft/nq/5ff9020d2a.gif" alt="I am nerdier than 96% of all people. Are you a nerd? Click here to take the Nerd Test, get geeky images and jokes, and talk on the nerd forum!"></a>
```

Image url is `http` -> change that to `https` and use this html on your profile. I use this as a answer.

[image: I am nerdier than 96% of all people. Are you a nerd? Click here to take the Nerd Test, get geeky images and jokes, and talk on the nerd forum!]

Comment: I know about flair widget and mentioned link, but where is HTML page in stackoverflow profile editor?

Comment: I paste it on current editing profile section, and apparently work! +1

Comment: How can I put on a flag like your profile?

Comment: :D upload image via SO it's goes to i.stack.imgur.com  and its display on your profile :)

Comment: What's "SO"? :D stackoverflow?

Comment: SO / SE same thing you understand that :). Now enjoy SO  channel .

Comment: I updated my question with nerdy widget example, I was tried to add the nerdy widget but apparently, SO does not support this widget, however this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) did it. how?

Comment: See updated answer.